# Como obter dados de um observable firebase?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic, firebase, typescript

Tenho uma lista que é carregada, vinda do firebase. Essa lista possui 3 atributos, valor, id, e data. Só que vou precisar capturar apenas um desses atributos e montar um array com eles, para então realizar um cálculo matemático, eu preciso extrair dali a propriedade (valor). Pesquisei sobre map, e subscribe, mas não consegui obter um resultado satisfatório, me retorna sempre [object Object] no console. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
  recompensas : Observable<Recompensa[]>;//meu observable
  public recompensa = {} as Recompensa;//meu model de dados

  //exibindo a minha lista na view
  ionViewDidLoad() {
     this.recompensas = this.recompensaProvider.buscarRecompensa(true);
  }  


  //minha tentativa de realizar o map e subscribe, sempre obtenho [object 
  //Object] no console
  teste() {
      const test = this.recompensas.subscribe(recs => recs.map(rec => 
      rec.valor ));
      console.log('valor de teste : '+test);
  }

  teste() {
      const test = this.recompensas.map(recs => recs.map(rec => 
      rec.valor ));
      console.log('valor de teste : '+test);
  }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

No seu método `teste()` você faz

```
teste() {
  const test = this.recompensas.subscribe(recs => recs.map(rec => 
  rec.valor ));
  console.log('valor de teste : '+test);
}
```

Nesse caso o `const test` é um tipo `Subscription` pois está pegando o valor do seu `subscribe`, você está se inscrevendo corretamente mas para obter o valor você deve busca-lo dentro do subscribe, algo assim talvez funcione:

```
teste() {
  this.recompensas.subscribe(recs => {
    console.log('Seu array: ' + recs);
    recs.map(rec => console.log('Array mapeado por valor: ' + rec.valor))
  });
}
```

Comment: Utilizei conforme tu passou, só não consegui visualizar no console as informações. Não me trouxe nada

Comment: Se puder incluir o código do seu `buscarRecompensa()`, por gentileza

Comment: Aqui está o meu código do buscarRecompensa()
Ele vem de um provider : 



  // Este método será retorna uma lista das recompensas
  buscarRecompensa(recompensaSalva: boolean) {
    return this.afs
      .collection<Recompensa>(this.caminho, ref => {
        return ref.where('recompensaSalva', '==', recompensaSalva);
      })
      .snapshotChanges()
      .map(actions => {
        return actions.map(a => {
          const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Recompensa;
          const id = a.payload.doc.id;
          return { id, ...data };
        })
      });
  }

Comment: Minha dúvida era se o retorno é um `observable` mesmo, pelo `SnapshotChanges()` é sim. Sua _view_ está atualizando normalmente?

Comment: Isso, minha view atualiza normalmente. Exibo todas as recompensas que são cadastradas, com o valor e com a data.

Comment: Entendi. Quando você está chamando seu método `teste()`? Acredito então ser o valor assíncrono ainda não estar pronto quando você se inscreve nele, ideal seria chamar esse `teste()` com um botão que só chama-o depois da _view_ com o valor

Comment: É isso mesmo que estou fazendo, quando a view carrega eu coloquei um botão, eu clico nesse botão após as recompensas serem carregadas, para então executar essa função teste()

Comment: Não entendo porque ele não apareceria no subscribe então... pode ser um teste bobo, mas poderia tentar assim no seu método: `this.recompensas.subscribe(recs => console.log(recs))`

Comment: Também não retornou nada, também estou achando estranho isso

Comment: Será que seu método está sendo mesmo disparado? Testou colocar um `console.log('etc')` no método mesmo sem realização alguma de `subscribe`?

Comment: Sim, ele chama sim. Eu fiz o seguinte agora : 

this.recompensas.map(recs => this.valorTotal = recs.map(rec => rec.data ))

atribui o valor ao this.valorToral, porem ao imprimi-lo ele aparece como undefined

Comment: no lugar de rec.data é rec.valor, acabei digitando errado

Comment: Que estranho. Acho que só conseguiria te ajudar realmente com o código completo, pois pra mim não consigo imaginar que a view consiga mapear esses valores mas em um `subscribe` ou até mesmo no `map` não seja possível.

Comment: Agradeço a ajuda de todos que se prestaram a tentar ajudar. Eu consegui resolver o problema, postarei mais tarde o código aqui, se alguém precisar ou passar pelo mesmo problema.

Comment: Opa, que ótimo! Poste sim, com certeza será útil para quem já teve, terá e até para conhecimento.

Answer (score 0):

Tente fazer um retorno dessa forma. Acredito vai ter sucesso.

```
  Observable<List<Recompensa>> get recompesa =>
      Observable(_collection.snapshots().map((query) => query.documents
          .map<Recompensa>((document) => Recompensa.fromMap(document))
          .toList()));
```